# Show one layout at a time in Horizontalscrollview in android

Tags: android

I want to create a screen which will be similar to Level design in Android games. so the screen will have a background image (easy to do) and then a view (i think LinearLayout is the best option) which will be at the center of the screen. This layout will have Level number (similar to many android games like bubble shooter). Now when the user does a swipe from left to right or vice versa these levels gets either incremented or decremented. I tried many ways but unable to show one layout at a time in Horizontalscrollview. Can anyone please suggest a way where one layout is shown at a time in horizontalscrollview and when users swipe we show the other layout.

Comment: Take a look at using a `ViewPager` with fragments for your layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at android.widget.ViewFlipper
It is not include swipe functionality, but you can inherit your custom class form ViewFlipper like below and add your level views to it:

```
public class Fipper extends ViewFlipper {

private final static int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 80;
private final static int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 150;

public Flipper(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public Flipper(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    final GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(new SwipeGestureDetector());
    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
            detector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void showPrevious() {
    if (getDisplayedChild() <= 0)
        return;

    setInAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_in_left);
    setOutAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_out_right);
    super.showPrevious();
}

@Override
public void showNext() {
    if (getDisplayedChild() >= getChildCount() - 1)
        return;

    setInAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_in_right);
    setOutAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_out_left);
    super.showNext();
}


private class SwipeGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            // right to left swipe
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                showNext();
                return true;
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                showPrevious();
                return true;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
}
```